# Internal Mic not recording sound in ASUS RoG, Ubuntu OS

Tags: ubuntu, microphone, asus

I recently bought an ASUS ROG PC thinking 'what could go wrong'.
Perhaps now I am paying the price.. at least I got over the hurdle of hDPI.
Now, I got a internal microphone problem.

- The internal microphone works in Windows, does not in Ubuntu
- System indeed reports microphone, but only dead silence could be recorded
- Tried restarting alsa & pulseaudio, meddling with alsamixer volumes, ineffective
- One strange thing: alsamixer shows NVIDIA initially, and I have to switch to Realtek to control the sounds
- Looking at what happens right after enabling the microphone, it seems like adaptive audio is filtering any signal - but I don't know

How do I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: After countless installs, it fixed itself. Seems like the input was previously over-adjusting to initial high pitch input after unmute.